# Making AFJSONRequestOperation synchronous

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation, synchronous

I have adopted a bunch of code where it is using AFNetworking for REST calls. The problem is that all those calls are made in synchronous manner. Which way of making AFJSONOperation from asynchronous, to synchronous would you recommend as best?

I have seen GCD based example so far but I don't see it simple as it is not easy to read. I would turn to set a few NSOperation objects to tangle them up until response is catched.

I know that subject is controversial but I want to explore this way of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for synchronicity, then NSOperations are the exact opposite of a tool for it.  NSOperationQueue is built on top of GCD, and can only run in an asynchronous manner (in fact, that's the reason the class exists in the first place).  You can subclass NSOperationQueue to provide some level of synchronicity, but it would have to be through GCD as well.  Look into `dispatch_sync()` and `dispatch_barrier_sync()`, which you can use to call a given operation's `-main` method on the queue returned by `dispatch_get_current_queue()`.

But all of this is far too much for solving a race condition.  Look, instead, into dependent operations, or even maintaining asynchronicity, but with a serial queue so execution order is maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify, the goal is to pause thread, perform those asynchronous operations and resume the thread with result of asynchronous calls, so the original call stack is preserved.